# React AntDesign add uploaded images to FormData

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to use [image uploader from AntDesign library](https://ant.design/components/upload). Here is a [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWoUU.png)

```
import { Upload, Icon, Modal } from 'antd'

class PicturesWall extends React.Component {
  state = {
    previewVisible: false,
    previewImage: '',
    fileList: [],
  }

  handleCancel = () => this.setState({ previewVisible: false })

  handlePreview = file => {
    this.setState({
      previewImage: file.url || file.thumbUrl,
      previewVisible: true,
    })
  }

  handleChange = ({ fileList }) => this.setState({ fileList })

  render() {
    const { previewVisible, previewImage, fileList } = this.state
    const uploadButton = (
      <div>
        <Icon type="plus" />
        <div className="ant-upload-text">Upload</div>
      </div>
    )
    return (
      <div className="clearfix">
        <Upload
          action="//jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/"
          listType="picture-card"
          fileList={fileList}
          onPreview={this.handlePreview}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        >
          {fileList.length >= 3 ? null : uploadButton}
        </Upload>
        <Modal
          visible={previewVisible}
          footer={null}
          onCancel={this.handleCancel}
        >
          <img alt="example" style={{ width: '100%' }} src={previewImage} />
        </Modal>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<PicturesWall />, mountNode)
```

It's so hard to understand what's going on here for me .
Can I get images from this component using something like 
**const img=event.target.files[0];**?

All I want it's put that uploaded images into array and using FormData send axios.post request to the backend.
I'm newbie in React .If it's something obvious pardon me.Thank you in advance

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`antd`'s `Upload` component is doing the upload for you under the hood. But if you don't want to do that, and upload the file later, you can also achieve that with the help of `beforeUpload` prop.

[From the docs](https://ant.design/components/upload/#API):

> `beforeUpload`: Hook function which will be executed before uploading. Uploading will be stopped with false or a rejected Promise returned. Warning：this function is not supported in IE9

I have written an example and added comments where necessary:

```
class PicturesWall extends React.Component {
  state = {
    previewVisible: false,
    previewImage: "",
    fileList: []
  };

  handleCancel = () => this.setState({ previewVisible: false });

  handlePreview = file => {
    this.setState({
      previewImage: file.thumbUrl,
      previewVisible: true
    });
  };

  handleUpload = ({ fileList }) => {
    //---------------^^^^^----------------
    // this is equivalent to your "const img = event.target.files[0]"
    // here, antd is giving you an array of files, just like event.target.files
    // but the structure is a bit different that the original file
    // the original file is located at the `originFileObj` key of each of this files
    // so `event.target.files[0]` is actually fileList[0].originFileObj
    console.log('fileList', fileList);

    // you store them in state, so that you can make a http req with them later
    this.setState({ fileList });
  };

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    let formData = new FormData();
    // add one or more of your files in FormData
    // again, the original file is located at the `originFileObj` key
    formData.append("file", this.state.fileList[0].originFileObj);

    axios
      .post("http://api.foo.com/bar", formData)
      .then(res => {
        console.log("res", res);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("err", err);
      });
  };

  render() {
    const { previewVisible, previewImage, fileList } = this.state;
    const uploadButton = (
      <div>
        <Icon type="plus" />
        <div className="ant-upload-text">Upload</div>
      </div>
    );
    return (
      <div>
        <Upload
          listType="picture-card"
          fileList={fileList}
          onPreview={this.handlePreview}
          onChange={this.handleUpload}
          beforeUpload={() => false} // return false so that antd doesn't upload the picture right away
        >
          {uploadButton}
        </Upload>

        <Button onClick={this.handleSubmit} // this button click will trigger the manual upload
        >
            Submit
        </Button>

        <Modal
          visible={previewVisible}
          footer={null}
          onCancel={this.handleCancel}
        >
          <img alt="example" style={{ width: "100%" }} src={previewImage} />
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<PicturesWall />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! This is second time you helped me  . Visibly you are expert in React!

Comment: Knowing that beforeUpload needs to return false, was helpful

Comment: @mehamasum, could you help please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65306114/upload-image-in-react-does-not-return-form-data-values

Comment: Do we have antd upload's equivalent for React-native..? Our API POST request requires, File object as instance of UploadFile (https://ant.design/components/upload/#UploadFile). Give me some hint for this.