# Upload image in react does not return form data values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get form data values uploading images.

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Upload, Button, Form } from "antd";

export default function App() {
  const normFile = (e) => {
    const fd = new FormData();
    const getFileList = e.fileList.map((i) => {
      return fd.append("upload", i.originFileObj);
    });
    console.log("formadata values", fd);
    if (Array.isArray(e)) {
      return e;
    }
    return e && e.fileList;
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <Form name="form" className="form">
          <Form.Item
            name="upload"
            className="upload"
            valuePropName="fileList"
            getValueFromEvent={normFile}
          >
            <Upload name="img" listType="picture">
              <Button className="btn">upload images</Button>
            </Upload>
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Trying to access `console.log("formadata values", fd);` i don't get anything there.
 Question: How to get form data using my code?
demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-flower-82tbe?file=/src/App.js:0-883

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to see the values in the FormData you must use loop like below:

```
for (let value of fd.values()) {
   console.log(value);
}
```

you can also see the value of a certain data by using the key :

```
console.log(fd.get('key'));
```

Also be careful for append multi files by a key (in your code = "upload") in loop, your data will override and just one of them append in the end, for uploading multi files by an input you must use the `[]` after the name of input like below:

```
const getFileList = e.fileList.map((i) => {
   return fd.append("upload[]", i.originFileObj);
});
```